# Using AnimatedList inside Riverpod AsyncValue

Tags: flutter, riverpod

So I am trying to update a AnimatedList with a StreamProvider. I can't use `AsyncValue.when`because it will update the state within build. So I created a Notifier and put the list key inside a provider as well.

```dart
final animatedKeyProvider = Provider((ref) => GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>());

class ChatNotifier extends Notifier<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> {
  @override
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> build() {
    return List<Map<String, dynamic>>.empty();
  }

  void addMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    state = [...state, message];
    ref.read(animatedKeyProvider).currentState!.insertItem(state.length);
  }

  void addAllMessages(List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages) {
    state = [...state, ...messages];
  }
}

final chatNotifierProvider =
    NotifierProvider<ChatNotifier, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  () => ChatNotifier(),
);
```

The StreamProvider declaration:

```dart
final chatProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final uid = ref.watch(userStreamProvider).value!.uid;
  final chatId = ref.watch(chatIdProvider);
  return ref
      .watch(docRefProvider('$uid/user_data/chats/$chatId'))
      .snapshots()
      .asBroadcastStream();
});
```

Inside widget I use `ref.listen` to update the Notifier state.

```dart
ref.listen(chatProvider, (previous, next) {
      final newMessages = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
          next.value?.data()!['messages'] ?? []);
      if (newMessages.isEmpty) {
        return;
      }

      if (next.isLoading) {
        ref.read(isMainLoadingProvider.notifier).state = false;
        return;
      }

      if (next.hasError) {
        ref.read(isMainLoadingProvider.notifier).state = false;
        ref.read(isMainErrorProvider.notifier).state = true;
      }

      if (next.hasValue) {
        ref.read(isMainLoadingProvider.notifier).state = false;
        if (messages.isEmpty) {
          ref.read(chatNotifierProvider.notifier).addAllMessages(newMessages);
          return;
        }
        ref.read(chatNotifierProvider.notifier).addMessage(newMessages.last);
      }

      final oldMessages = previous?.value?.data()!['messages'];
      if (oldMessages != null && newMessages.length > oldMessages.length) {
        listKey.currentState!.insertItem(newMessages.length - 1);
      }
      ref.read(isChatFullProvider.notifier).state =
          newMessages.length >= ref.read(chatLimitProvider);
    });
```

However I get this error when I initiate a chat. The chat is registered perfectly on the server side. And the chat is rendered and the animation is working.

```dart
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2
```

The index being passed on to by the `itemBuilder` seems to exceeds the length of `messages`. What am I seems to be doing wrong?